# How is the usage of chr(122 - (ord(char) - 97))

Tags: python, function

I'm not understanding how this line `chr(122 - (ord(char) - 97))` will work.

```
def encrypt_message(message):
    encrypted_message = ""
    for char in message:
        if char.isalpha():
            encrypted_char = chr(122 - (ord(char) - 97))         
            encrypted_message += encrypted_char
```

Comment: Looks like it translates each letter in the alphabet into its "opposite mirror" letter -- `a` becomes `z`, `b` becomes `y`, `c` becomes `x`, etc.  You would have seen this yourself, with a little bit of testing.

Comment: Don't hard-code ASCII codes like that. If they'd used `ord('a')` and `ord('z')` instead of 97 and 122 it would have been obvious what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

This will replace a letter with it's "symmetric" letter from the other end of the alphabet i.e. a = z, b = y, c = x, etc...

So how does this work?

1. We need to measure the "distance" from our original letter to `a`. We do this by looking at the `ord` `ord('a')` happens to be 97.
2. We then move that distance away from `z`. `ord('z')` happens to 122. This will get the `ord` of our replacement letter
3. Once we have the `ord`, we take the `chr` to get the actual letter.

Basically, for readability, the code could be expressed as `chr(ord(z) - (ord(char) - ord('a')))`, but replacing the `ord('z')` and `ord('a')` with their actual values save some calculation. The most optimal would be to simplify the math as `chr(219- ord(char))`.

Answer (score 0):

Basically this line of code gives the mirror letter of the alphabet...

You can inspect this line of code with the following:

```py
characters = 'abcdefghijklmopqrstuvwxyz'

enc_string = ''
for char in characters:
    encrypted_char = chr(122 - (ord(char) - 97))
    enc_string += encrypted_char

print(enc_string)
```

Which returns this:

```
zyxwvutsrqponlkjihgfedcba
```

Which is exactly as John pointed out in the comment. The characters have been changed to the mirror letters in the alphabet.

- `a` becomes `z`
- `b` becomes `y`
  . . .

and so on...